# Push notifications on iOS 8 and iOS 9 using Enterprise distribution

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, enterprise

I have created and app for a company which they'd like to distribute through Enterprise for their employees. When they do this using an iOS 9 version phone it works like a charm, but for iOS 8 they are never prompted with "Allow push notifications" so the app will never receive any. I looked through notifications in settings on the phone and it is turned on by default.

I've tried to set it to disable, make sure the app is terminated, then add it back to enabled and start app. I've tried removing the app, reinstalling it, rebooting and tried all steps again but it just won't work.

Anyone got any ideas?

### Edit

I now got the prompt. I still don't get any notifications though...I have two devices with iOS 8 and none of them receives the notification, and I have two devices with > iOS 9 and they both receive the notifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to see Notification alert, 
From Apple Doc [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42] it says that,

**The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.**

But if you want to check immediately, just do few things

1. Delete your app from the device.
2. Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
4. Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

But, by doing so you will get an alert to accept receive notifications.

From your saying, since push notifications is turned on by default (or accepted before), you should receive Notifications.

Please do comment.

Comment: I did this and got the prompt now. But I still don't receive any notifications...but it works fine on iOS 9.

Comment: @ClockWise if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } Use this. or     let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil)     UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

Comment: Thanks for the effort @user3487853 but half of that isn't even swift code.

Comment: Please check last lines of code which are written in swift. @ClockWise

Answer (score 0):

You must set up like this

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                                        (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound)
                                                                         categories:categories];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

check if user allow local notification of system setting

```
/**
 *  check if user allow local notification of system setting
 *
 *  @return YES-allowed,otherwise,NO.
 */
+ (BOOL)isAllowedNotification {
    //iOS8 check if user allow notification
    if ([UIDevice isSystemVersioniOS8]) {// system is iOS8
        UIUserNotificationSettings *setting = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
        if (UIUserNotificationTypeNone != setting.types) {
            return YES;
        }
    } else {//iOS7
        UIRemoteNotificationType type = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
        if(UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone != type)
            return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, is it possible you have a swift version lying around? Forgot to mention in OP. I got the prompt now, but I don't receive any notifications which might be because of the code you wrote here. Will try to convert it to swift.